# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetLayer'

Tags: python

I am new in Geo-Python and have been having trouble trying to fix an error in my code. The implementation of the two methods `data_to_shape` and `shape_to_raster` are shown in following also, in the module `geo_operator`. My main problem is that, while the shapefile and raster for map A are created perfectly, the shapefile of map B is created with troubles. I checked that by trying to open map B's shapefile in QGIS and it crashed. That is for sure the reason why I'm getting error messages of

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetLayer'

when the shape is passed as argument to the `shape_to_raster` method. But I tried everything and couldn't find why. I tried:

- using `gdf.to_file(filename=outputname, encoding='utf-8')`
- checking to see if I could read the map_B.shp (which I suspect is defectuous) and it worked out fine, it was normally read as gdf

```
import pandas as pd
import fiona; fiona.supported_drivers
import geo_operator


# Input Data
x_res_A = 0.1  # assuming these are the cell sizes
y_res_A = 0.01111  # change as appropriate
x_res_B = 0.2  # assuming these are the cell sizes
y_res_B = 0.01111  # change as appropriate
shape_A = "map_A.shp"
shape_B = "map_B.shp"
raster_A = "map_A.tif"
raster_B = "map_B.tif"

# Importing raw data into dataframe
data_A = pd.read_csv("hexagon_experiment.csv", skip_blank_lines=True)
data_B = pd.read_csv("hexagon_simulation.csv", skip_blank_lines=True)

# Create shapefile from dataframe
geo_operator.data_to_shape(data_A, shape_A)
geo_operator.data_to_shape(data_B, shape_B)

# Create Raster from shapefile
geo_operator.shape_to_raster(x_res_A, y_res_A, shape_A, raster_A)
geo_operator.shape_to_raster(x_res_B, y_res_B, shape_B, raster_B)
```

The geo_operator modules as:

```
import geopandas
import ogr
import gdal


def data_to_shape(data, outputname):
    # Create the dictionary with new label names and then rename for standardization
    new_names = {data.columns[0]: 'x', data.columns[1]: 'y', data.columns[2]: 'dz'}
    data = data.rename(columns=new_names)

    # Create geodataframe from the dataframe
    gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(data, geometry=geopandas.points_from_xy(data.x, data.y))
    gdf = gdf.drop(['x', 'y'], axis=1)  # exclude columns of labels x and y

    # Saving the shapefile
    gdf.to_file(outputname)


def shape_to_raster(x_res, y_res, _in, _out):
    # Open Shapefile and get layer
    source_ds = ogr.Open(_in)
    source_layer = source_ds.GetLayer()
    x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max = source_layer.GetExtent()

    # Set NoDataValue
    nodata_value = -9999

    # 4. Create Target - TIFF
    cols = int((x_max - x_min) / x_res)
    rows = int((y_max - y_min) / y_res)
    _raster = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create(_out, cols, rows, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)
    _raster.SetGeoTransform((x_min, x_res, 0, y_max, 0, -y_res))
    _band = _raster.GetRasterBand(1)
    _band.SetNoDataValue(nodata_value)

    # Rasterize
    gdal.RasterizeLayer(_raster, [1], source_layer, options=['ATTRIBUTE=dz'])
```

My data of map B looks as follows:
[hexagon_simulation.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x14xb.png)